# How can I get Chimchar in Pokemon Sun & Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I want Chimchar in Pokemon Sun & Moon. How can I get it?

I've been reading about QR Codes but there's one thing I don't understand. What's the purpose of scanning Chimchar's QR Code when it won't be catchable anyway? Because it doesn't appear in the Pokedex, and when I do a Island Scan, all I get are the 28 Pokemon that appear in this website https://daily.pokecommunity.com/2016/11/20/pokemon-sun-moon-qr-island-scan/

So... how can I get Chimchar?

Comment: QR codes come from other people's pokedexes. Since legendarys, UBs, and special pokemon like Type: Null don't have QR codes, this leads me to believe that you can only get QR codes for pokemon that can be caught in the wild.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot get it from Sun/Moon. You need to transfer it from a previous game, according to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/390.shtml) website.

You will be able to use [PokeBank](http://www.pokemonbank.com/) to transfer when it is available on Jan 2017.

You can use QR code to scan (almost) any Pokemon that is available from Gen 1 to Gen 7. However, not all of them are in Alolan PokeDex. Island Scan seems to be the only way, as of now (Dec 2016), to get some Pokemon that is not in the Pokedex.

**Update**:
PokeBank got an update on Jan 24, 2017. You can now transfer a Chimchar from previous generations through PokeBank. Note that PokeBank is a paid service.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot obtain a Chimchar in Pokémon Sun & Moon.

As you say, scanning the Pokédex entry for one won't accomplish anything since you can't find the Pokémon anywhere in Alola, even with Island Scans. Once Pokémon Bank is compatible with Sun & Moon, you'll be able to use it to transfer a Chimchar from previous games to the seventh generation.

Answer (score -6):

Actually the only current way of getting one is through Island Scan. Ive gotten Cyndaquil and Snivy so far.

Comment: Do you have a source to back this?  The other answers conflict with this.